# Naive Bayesian Classifier Implementtion In Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, implementation, naivebayes

I have implemented naive Bayesian classifier in Python. I ran my code using 1000,2000 and even 5000 tuples, but it is always giving 100% accuracy. Now I am doubtful about the implementation. Is it normal or i have done something wrong in my code. It is a 2-class classifier.

```
class_names=my_data[target].unique()
prob_class=[]


for clas in class_names:
    prob_class.append(float(len(my_data[my_data[target]==clas]))/float(len(my_data)))


def bayes_classify(x,my_train_data):
    max_prob=-1
    best_class=class_names[0]
    ind=0
    col_names=my_train_data.column_names()
    for clas in class_names:
        prob=prob_class[ind]
        pure_data=my_train_data[my_train_data[target]==clas]
        for col in col_names:
            if(my_train_data[col].dtype()==str):
                prob=prob*(float(len(pure_data[pure_data[col]==x[col]]))/float(len(pure_data)))
            else:    
                mean=pure_data[col].mean()
                stdev=pure_data[col].std()
                stdev=stdev+0.1
                exponent = math.exp(-(math.pow(x[col]-mean,2)/(2*math.pow(stdev,2))))
                prob=prob*(1 / (math.sqrt(2*math.pi)) * stdev) * exponent

        if(prob>max_prob):
            max_prob=prob
            best_class=clas
        ind=ind+1
    return best_class


def evaluate_bayes_classifier(my_test_data,my_train_data):
    prediction = my_test_data.apply(lambda x: bayes_classify(x,my_train_data))
    my_test_data['pred']=prediction
    target_values=my_test_data[target]
    mistakes=my_test_data.apply(lambda x: 1 if(x[target]!=x['pred']) else 0)
    cla_err=mistakes.sum()/float (len(mistakes))
    my_test_data.remove_column('pred')
    return target_values,prediction,cla_err



my_train_data, my_test_data = my_data.random_split(.8, seed=1)
targets,predictions,error=evaluate_bayes_classifier(my_test_data,my_train_data)
accuracy=(1-error)*100
```

[image: Train_data]

[image: Test_data]

Comment: Try running it with 5 tuples and see if it still gives 100%.

Comment: I took 6 tuples data and splitted it such that 5 tuples form train data and 1 tuple form train data. It is still giving 100% accuracy. I also used train data of 17 tuples and test data of 4 tuples, even also it is giving 100% accuracy.

Comment: What are these tuples? Can you post a sample of your data and output? What are you trying to train here?

Comment: race  max_glu_serum  glimepiride  rosiglitazone  insulin  change  diabetesMed
Caucasian  Norm  No  No  No  No  No
Caucasian  None  No  No  No  No  No
Caucasian  None  No  No  No  No  No
Caucasian  None  No  No  No  No  No
Caucasian  None  No  Up  No  Ch  Yes

Comment: Please refrain from supplementing the answer with details in the comments. Add it to your question, and format it neatly. Thank you!

Comment: I have added two images in the question. One of which is for train_data and other is for test_data.

Comment: I am predicting whether a person is affected by diabetes or not

Comment: On your screenshot it says accuracy 30%.

Comment: Before splitting the data into train_data and test_data, i have balanced the data. Now if i train with train_data and test with test_data, it is giving 100% accuracy. But if i train with train_data and test with whole UNBALANCED DATA it is giving 30% accuracy.

Comment: Where is the problem in code or in data.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ please help me.

Comment: Without any information on what my_data looks like, it isn't easy to say. That's a lot of code to sit and look at.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ  I have attached two screenshots in the question. One is of training data and another is of test data. In the data there are 7 columns and last column named as diabetesMed is the class label. Class label is Yes if that person is suffering from diabetes otherwise it is No. Other 6 columns are race,max_glu_serum,glimepiride,rosiglitazone, insulin, and change.